# Javascript regex to replace last digit occurence between square brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been looking for this for hours, right now I've ended in a very ugly way (but working). I would like to find a reusable nice way to do this.

I've a string like this:

```
wanna[0].some[0].javascript
```

I would like to replace the last digit occurence between square brackets:

```
wanna[0].some[1].javascript
```

I've ended this (ugly) way:

```
myString.replace(/\d].javascript$/, "1].javascript")
```

which should be the best regex to match that?

```
myString.replace(/\d/, 1) // this should be for the first digit
myString.replace(/\d/g, 1) // this for every digit
```

I've read about negative look-ahead but I still didn't get if JS supports this.

Comment: This seems like an odd problem to solve. What are you actually trying to do? See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: I've commented the other answer with some more information. I'm going probably to edit my question tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a negative lookahead to ascertain that there are no more brackets after the one you're matching:

```
var text = 'wanna[0].some[0].javascript';

text = text.replace(/\[\d](?!.*\[)/, '[1]');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bRkEP/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need lookahead. The answer you gave (though ugly) should work. As Crockford says of negative lookaheads in *JavaScript: The Good Parts*: 'This is not a good part.'

If the line you provided isn't working I imagine it's because you haven't escaped the square bracket. It should be:

```
myString.replace(/\d\].javascript$/, "1].javascript");
```

You could also do some capturing to make it easier on the eye.

I agree with the comment to your question that it seems like an odd problem to solve. Why are you changing the number in a string? This looks like something that would be better served with a number variable in the square brackets that you can then increment.

Comment: I'm creating some textareas dinamically and I'm cloning the first one incrementing the name . That's because I'm using AutoPopulatingList to create them on the server side. :)